# Client method called by ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager, registerstartupscript

Can somebody look at the below code and tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
for(i=0;i<=Request.Files.Count;i++)
{

int percentComplete = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(i + 1) / (double)Request.Files.Count * 100);
string message = string.Format("{0} of {1} uploaded", i + 1, Request.Files.Count);

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "progress", @"do_progress("+message+","+percentComplete+");", true);

}
```

I am trying to update the client with each pass of the loop. On the client (inside of the form tags) I have a function called "do_progress" that takes two parameters: message and percent. My intention is that the client-side method fires with each pass of the loop but nothing happens.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your help. Ramiz, your code won't work in my case because it collects all the methods (and progress) inside the loop and then sends them to the client at the same time.
This won't show progress accurately (each loop represents the completion of an uploaded file). I need to be accessing the client function, do_progress, after each unique completion of the server-side loop.

Also, the page has already loaded and the code is fired when a (upload) button is clicked.

Having said that, I am still having problems. I can confirm that I am getting the results I want with the below code by looking at 'selection source':

```
int percentComplete = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(i + 1) / (double)Request.Files.Count * 100);

string message = string.Format("{0} of {1} uploaded", i + 1, Request.Files.Count);

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "progress" + i, @"do_progress('" + message + "','" + percentComplete + "');", true);
```

But, I am not seeing the results update in real-time on the client. The progress bar isn't moving and the counter (n of n files) isn't doing anything. But, when I look at the innerHTML, the values have updated. Very odd. It is almost like I need to be refreshing the page or something but that should't be necessary.

The client side function I am using, which is placed in the form tags at the end of the page, looks like this:

```
function do_progress(message,percent)
                    {
                        try {
                            $('progress_status').innerHTML = message;
                            $('progress_bar').attr("style", percent + "px"); 
                        }catch(e){alert(e.message)};
                    }
```

Comment: try RegisterClientScriptBlock instead of RegisterStartupScript

Comment: whether you want this in page load or a click event...

Answer (score 0):

**`message`** is a **`string`** value it should be enclosed in single quote `"do_progress('"+message+"',"+percentComplete+");"`

**`percentComplete`** contains **`integer`** so it doesn't require to enclose in single quote as **`message`** does.

```
string methods = string.empty;

for(i=0;i<=Request.Files.Count;i++)
{

int percentComplete = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(i + 1) / (double)Request.Files.Count * 100);
string message = string.Format("{0} of {1} uploaded", i + 1, Request.Files.Count);

methods += "do_progress('"+message+"','"+percentComplete+"');"

}
```

Secondly, here, I'm incrementing all methods in a **`string`** variable and calling it in **`window.onload`** event just make sure the **`DOM`** is ready before we call the **`do_progress`** function.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "progress", @"window.onload = function() {"+ methods +"}", true);
```

However, this should not require here, call in **`window.onload`** as **`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`** will call them when **`DOM`** gets ready.

I'm not sure what exactly issue at your end but this is my instant review.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this.RegisterStartupScript instead of ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Answer (score 0):

Your client side `do_progress` function appears to have an error in the jQuery selectors - you're currently looking for **elements** named `progress_status` and `progress_bar` when I suspect you intend to be looking for classes or IDs.  If your selector doesn't match anything it doesn't raise any kind of error, it just doesn't do anything.